# How to create angular2 library project ?

Tags: angular

I see [this info](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/) , but is it still relevant for angular2 release ? with the module import export . I is there any boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not relevant any more. Lots of core changes makes important parts in this post obsolete and very much outdated. On the other hand, this question doesn't really belong here, but that's okay. You better search for a more relevant guide, or just check the [**angular site**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) about `NgModule`.